# What is the correct target for the JAVA_HOME environment variable for a Linux OpenJDK Debian-based distribution?

Tags: java, grails, java-home, debian-based

In Windows, `JAVA_HOME` must point to the JDK installation folder (so that `JAVA_HOME/bin` contains all executables and `JAVA_HOME/libs` contains all default `jar` libraries).

If I download Sun's JDK bundle and installs it in Linux, it is the same procedure.

However, I need to use Kubuntu's default OpenJDK package. The problem is that all executables are placed in `/usr/bin`. But the jars are placed in `/usr/share/java`. Since they are not under the same `JAVA_HOME` folder I'm having trouble with Grails and maybe there will be trouble with other applications that expect the standard Java structure.

1. If I use:

   ```
   JAVA_HOME=/usr
   ```

   All applications and scripts that want to use any Java executable can use the standard procedure `call $JAVA_HOME/bin/executable`. However, since the jars are in a different place, they are not always found (example: in grails I'm getting `ClassDefNotFound` for `native2ascii`).
2. On the other hand, if I use:

   ```
   JAVA_HOME=/usr/share/java
   ```

   None of the Java executables (`java`, `javac`, etc.) can be found.

So, what is the correct way of handling the `JAVA_HOME` variable in a Debian-based Linux?

Thanks for your help,
Luis

Answer (score 103, accepted):

What finally worked for me (Grails now works smoothly) is doing almost like Steve B. has pointed out:

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/default-java
```

This way if the user changes the default JDK for the system, `JAVA_HOME` still works.

`default-java` is a symlink to the current JVM.

Comment: It seems there is no such link on Debian 7

Comment: On RHEL5.10, it is /usr/lib/jvm/java

Comment: I used /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64

Comment: For Oracle Linux 7 (this _should_ apply to CentOS and RHEL), I created a file called /etc/profile.d/java.sh and populated it with the following:

JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jre-openjdk
export JAVA_HOME

after re-sourcing /etc/profile (by running source /etc/profile) JAVA_HOME was populated as expected.

Answer (score 89):

If you use alternatives to manage multiple java versions, you can set the `JAVA_HOME` based on the symlinked java (or javac) like this:

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(readlink -f /usr/bin/java | sed "s:bin/java::")
```

Comment: This works for me: JAVA_HOME=$(readlink -f /usr/bin/java | sed "s:/jre/bin/java::")

Comment: Brilliant solution, solves my years long headaches with JAVA_HOME, which tends to point to different places on different operating systems.

Comment: note that this clever solution won't work on distros like Gentoo that have `/usr/bin/java` pointing to a script (`/usr/libexec/eselect-java/run-java-tool.bash`). still, it's a nice approach. the only thing i'd change is use Bash's builtin substitution to avoid spawning `sed`, e.g.: `JAVA_HOME=$( j=$( readlink -f /usr/bin/java ) ; echo ${j%%/bin/java} )`

Comment: This works well :) Might want to change `javac` to `java` because not everyone has the JDK installed; only the JRE

Comment: @AlexisWilke now java instead of javac

Comment: my symlink /use/bin/java points to jre/bin/java, this causes an error during compilation as I need it to point to Java jdk home.

Answer (score 7):

The standard Ubuntu install seems to put the various Java versions in `/usr/lib/jvm`. The `javac`, java you find in your path will softlink to this.

There's no issue with installing your own Java version anywhere you like, as long as you set the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable and make sure to have the new Java `bin` on your path.

A simple way to do this is to have the Java home exist as a softlink, so that if you want to upgrade or switch versions you only have to change the directory that this points to - e.g.:

```
/usr/bin/java --> /opt/jdk/bin/java,

/opt/jdk --> /opt/jdk1.6.011
```

Comment: it is dangerous to recommend Ubuntu solutions with Debian. They can and do vary.

Comment: Note the requestor said he used Kubuntu, so Ubuntu solutions should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

I modified one of the solution above and this seems to work no matter where java is installed, as long it's in your PATH.

```
JAVA_HOME=$( j=$( readlink -f $(which java) ) ; echo ${j%%/bin/java} )
```

Comment: See https://www.baeldung.com/find-java-home for options.

Answer (score 0):

I usually don't have any JAVA_HOME environment variable. Java can set it up itself. Inside java java.home system property should be available.

Comment: I usually don't have it either. However, if I don't set it up, grails complains that JAVA_HOME is not there and aborts.

Comment: ant needs it too in debian which is the context

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the JAVA_LIB variable also.

Answer (score 0):

If you have issues with JAR files not being found I would also ensure your CLASSPATH is set to include the location of those files.  I do find however that the CLASSPATH often needs to be set differently for different programs and often ends up being something to set uniquely for individual programs.

Answer (score 0):

Updated answer that will solve your problem and also just a general good how-to for installing Oracle Java 7 on Ubuntu can be found here: http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Oracle-Java-on-Ubuntu-Linux

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered similar problems with the openjdk-6-jre and openjdk-6-jre-headless packages in Ubuntu.

My problem was solved by purging the openjdk-6-jre and openjdk-6-jre-headless packages and re-installing. The alternatives are only updated on a fresh install of the openjdk-6-jre and openjdk-6-jre-headless packages.

Below is a sample of installing after purging:

```
aptitude purge openjdk-6-jre openjdk-6-jre-headless # to ensure no configuration exists
aptitude install --without-recommends openjdk-6-jre # Installing without some extras
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Reading extended state information
Initializing package states... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  ca-certificates-java{a} java-common{a} libavahi-client3{a} libavahi-common-data{a} libavahi-common3{a} libcups2{a} libflac8{a} libgif4{a} libnspr4-0d{a} libnss3-1d{a} libogg0{a} libpulse0{a} libsndfile1{a} libvorbis0a{a} libvorbisenc2{a} libxi6{a} libxtst6{a}
  openjdk-6-jre openjdk-6-jre-headless{a} openjdk-6-jre-lib{a} tzdata-java{a}
The following packages are RECOMMENDED but will NOT be installed:
  icedtea-6-jre-cacao icedtea-netx ttf-dejavu-extra
0 packages upgraded, 21 newly installed, 0 to remove and 119 not upgraded.
Need to get 0B/34.5MB of archives. After unpacking 97.6MB will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n/?]
Writing extended state information... Done
Selecting previously deselected package openjdk-6-jre-lib.
(Reading database ... 62267 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking openjdk-6-jre-lib (from .../openjdk-6-jre-lib_6b24-1.11.5-0ubuntu1~10.04.2_all.deb) ...
...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Setting up tzdata-java (2012e-0ubuntu0.10.04) ...
...
Setting up openjdk-6-jre-headless (6b24-1.11.5-0ubuntu1~10.04.2) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/bin/java to provide /usr/bin/java (java) in auto mode.
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/bin/keytool to provide /usr/bin/keytool (keytool) in auto mode.
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/bin/pack200 to provide /usr/bin/pack200 (pack200) in auto mode.
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/bin/rmid to provide /usr/bin/rmid (rmid) in auto mode.
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/bin/rmiregistry to provide /usr/bin/rmiregistry (rmiregistry) in auto mode.
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/bin/unpack200 to provide /usr/bin/unpack200 (unpack200) in auto mode.
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/bin/orbd to provide /usr/bin/orbd (orbd) in auto mode.
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/bin/servertool to provide /usr/bin/servertool (servertool) in auto mode.
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/bin/tnameserv to provide /usr/bin/tnameserv (tnameserv) in auto mode.
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/jexec to provide /usr/bin/jexec (jexec) in auto mode.
Setting up openjdk-6-jre (6b24-1.11.5-0ubuntu1~10.04.2) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/bin/policytool to provide /usr/bin/policytool (policytool) in auto mode.
...
```

You can see above that `update-alternatives` is run to set up links for the various Java binaries.

After this install, there are also links in `/usr/bin`, links in `/etc/alternatives`, and files for each binary in `/var/lib/dpkg/alternatives`.

```
ls -l /usr/bin/java /etc/alternatives/java /var/lib/dpkg/alternatives/java
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  40 2013-01-16 14:44 /etc/alternatives/java -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/bin/java
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  22 2013-01-16 14:44 /usr/bin/java -> /etc/alternatives/java
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 158 2013-01-16 14:44 /var/lib/dpkg/alternatives/java
```

Let's contast this with installing without purging.

```
aptitude remove openjdk-6-jre
aptitude install --without-recommends openjdk-6-jre
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Reading extended state information
Initializing package states... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  ca-certificates-java{a} java-common{a} libavahi-client3{a} libavahi-common-data{a} libavahi-common3{a} libcups2{a} libflac8{a} libgif4{a} libnspr4-0d{a} libnss3-1d{a} libogg0{a} libpulse0{a} libsndfile1{a} libvorbis0a{a} libvorbisenc2{a} libxi6{a} libxtst6{a}
  openjdk-6-jre openjdk-6-jre-headless{a} openjdk-6-jre-lib{a} tzdata-java{a}
The following packages are RECOMMENDED but will NOT be installed:
  icedtea-6-jre-cacao icedtea-netx ttf-dejavu-extra
0 packages upgraded, 21 newly installed, 0 to remove and 119 not upgraded.
Need to get 0B/34.5MB of archives. After unpacking 97.6MB will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n/?]
Writing extended state information... Done
Selecting previously deselected package openjdk-6-jre-lib.
(Reading database ... 62293 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking openjdk-6-jre-lib (from .../openjdk-6-jre-lib_6b24-1.11.5-0ubuntu1~10.04.2_all.deb) ...
...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
...
Setting up openjdk-6-jre-headless (6b24-1.11.5-0ubuntu1~10.04.2) ...

Setting up openjdk-6-jre (6b24-1.11.5-0ubuntu1~10.04.2) ...
...
```

As you see, `update-alternatives` is not triggered.

After this install, there are no files for the Java binaries in `/var/lib/dpkg/alternatives`, no links in `/etc/alternatives`, and no links in `/usr/bin`.

The removal of the files in `/var/lib/dpkg/alternatives` also breaks `update-java-alternatives`.

Answer (score 0):

As an update for fedora user , alternatives set current java directory to 
/usr/java/default

so you have to set your JAVA_HOME to /usr/java/default to always have alternatives curent selection in your classpath

HTH !

Answer (score 0):

I always tend to set the JAVA_HOME according to the `/usr/bin/java`.

```
JAVA_HOME="$(dirname -- "$(dirname -- "$(readlink -f /usr/bin/java)")")"
```

This way, both alternatives point to the same location

Answer (score -1):

Please see what the update-alternatives command does (it has a nice man...).

Shortly - what happens when you have java-sun-1.4 and java-opensouce-1.0 ... which one takes "java"? It debian "/usr/bin/java" is symbolic link and "/usr/bin/java-sun-1.4" is an alternative to "/usr/bin/java"

Edit:
As Richard said, `update-alternatives` is not enough. You actually need to use `update-java-alternatives`. More info at:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java

Comment: update-alternatives is not enough. It needs to be update-java-alternatives

Comment: @Richard: yes, noted. First time I head about it so I googled, and found Ubuntu's documentation. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

As far as I remember, I used the update-java-alternatives script instead of the update-alternatives. And it did set the JAVA_HOME for me correctly.

Comment: It doesn't in Ubuntu 20.4

Answer (score -1):

Ubuntu 12.04 this works...

JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/jre

Answer (score -2):

My correct target has always been to download it from Sun and just install it that way.  Then you know exactly what directory everything goes in.

But if you'd prefer to stick with the odd way that Debian installs it, my best guess would be the parent directory just above where the java and javac binaries are located.

(since when you specify it in your path it's $JAVA_HOME/bin)
(So in your case it would be ...  $JAVA_HOME/share and $JAVA_HOME would be /usr ?)

Eh, that doesn't sound right...

I'm interested to hear the answer to this too!

Comment: When using debian you really need to keep with the debian structures or later system updates will leave you with a broken system.