# What is the correct path for JAVA_HOME on a Linux system that uses alternatives?

Tags: java, java-home

Determining the correct path for `JAVA_HOME` is a bit complex on an **Ubuntu** system because it uses alternatives. On my machine this is how alternatives creates at least two levels of indirection before it gets to the actual java or javac.

```
usr/bin/javac -> /etc/alternatives/

/etc/alternatives/java -> /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7/bin/javac
```

If I set `JAVA_HOME` to `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7` , then it is possible that my system java might become inconsistent with the java pointed to by `JAVA_HOME`, if I update alternatives to use another java.

My question is, what is the correct value for `JAVA_HOME` on a system that uses alternatives. I am inclined to think that `JAVA_HOME` should be set to `/usr`

This way **TOMCAT** or any other software that uses it, will append 'bin' to `JAVA_HOME` and find all the executables it needs.

Is this the correct value for `JAVA_HOME` on systems that use alternatives. Do most software use `JAVA_HOME` only to locate the executables, or would they use the value to locate other artifacts (such as the security policy fil, etc) that come bundled with the JDK ? If the former is true, then I feel we can use `/usr` for `JAVA_HOME`, but if the latter is true, then I think the only way to use `JAVA_HOME` correctly is by sacrificing the alternatives functionality.

Comment: I just looked on my CentOS 5.5 system: 1) I do *not* have $JAVA_HOME defined anywhere in my environment, 2) /etc/tomcat5/tomcat5.conf has this line: `JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java"`, 3) /usr/lib/jvm/java is a symlink: `java -> /etc/alternatives/java_sdk`, 4) /etc/alternatives/java_sdk is also a symlink: `java_sdk -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.4.2-gcj`.

Comment: Yes, I have 'default-java' on Ubuntu instead of 'java' inside /usr/lib/jvm So, I guess the trick is to not worry about alternatives at all because there is one more layer between alternatives and Java.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Good question - I use "alternatives" on Linux and everything "just works" - I never really had to think about it.

I believe this is the answer:

- `JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/default-java`
- [What is the correct target for the JAVA_HOME envrionment variable for a Linux OpenJDK Debian-based distribution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/663658/what-is-the-correct-target-for-the-java-home-envrionment-variable-for-a-linux-op)

1)  "alternatives" sets the symlink to whatever your "real" Java is currently configured to

2) All you need to do is set $JAVA_HOME to the symlink

Comment: On which distro is this? I'm on Debian, which uses alternatives, and I don't have a /usr/lib/jvm/default-java

Comment: Interesting answer. I first started this comment with an explanation of why, what you are suggesting will not work. But as I thought of it more I think I understand what you are suggesting. Are you saying that I should create a 'default-java' directory and symlink it to the Java I want to use. Following this I should update my alternatives system to point all Java related binaries to the ones in 'default-java/bin'. This will solve the problem by adding one more layer between alternatives and Java

Comment: Thanks. I was a bit confused because I had messed around with my alternatives, and the java binaries were no longer going through default-java

Comment: It seems to be JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java for redhat.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find a proper direct solution for the issue, so here is my workaround
add the following to the bachrc

```
javapath=$( readlink --canonicalize /usr/bin/java)
removebin="/bin/java"
removejre="/jre"
javapath2=${javapath/$removebin/}
export JAVA_HOME=${javapath2/$removejre/}
```

Then do source to reload the JAVA_HOME whenever you change the java version using alternatives

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Explanation:
What I have done is get the java classpath from the variable set by update-alternatives app and then remove the bin/java part from it and then assign it to the JAVA_HOME. This process happens at login to the system. if you alter the java version in the middle of a session you will have to reload the profile.