# Error on adding platform in Ionic Framework on Windows

Tags: cordova, ant, ionic-framework

I get the following error while adding the Android platform. I had checked my `ant -version` and it outputted it correctly. Also, I noticed when it created the myApp folder `node_modules` wasn't fetched with it. Beneath is output from my console:

```
Adding platform android
Creating android project...

C:\Users\user\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.5.0\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error: An error occurred while listing Android targets
    at C:\Users\user\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.5.0\bin\lib\check_reqs.js
:87:29
    at _rejected (C:\Users\user\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.5.0\bin\node_m
odules\q\q.js:808:24)
    at C:\Users\user\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.5.0\bin\node_modules\q\q.
js:834:30
    at Promise.when (C:\Users\user\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.5.0\bin\nod
e_modules\q\q.js:1079:31)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\Riliwan\.cordova\lib\android\co
rdova\3.5.0\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:752:41)
    at C:\Users\user\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.5.0\bin\node_modules\q\q.
js:574:44
    at flush (C:\Users\user\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.5.0\bin\node_modul
es\q\q.js:108:17)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)
Error: C:\Users\user\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.5.0\bin\create.bat: Comma
nd failed with exit code 8
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\Riliwan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\
cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\superspawn.js:131:23)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:753:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:820:5)
Unable to add platform android. Please see console for more info.
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and fixed it by setting these paths to the O.S. Path:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/home/coutinho/android-sdk 
export ANDROID_TOOLS=/home/coutinho/android-sdk/tools/  
export ANDROID_PLATFORM_TOOLS=/home/coutinho/android-sdk/platform-tools/

PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME:$ANDROID_TOOLS:$ANDROID_PLATFORM_TOOLS:.
```

Then it worked fine.

Comment: Thanks rafael! i also noticed i needed to install an android SDK from your answer

Comment: I have added those paths but still getting problems. I'm on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: +1 . I have 12.04 and I had added ANDROID_TOOLS and ANDROID_PLATFORM_TOOLS , but adding ANDROID_HOME did the job for me. Strange, it is not mentioned in official instructions.

Comment: Even me having the same problems with different error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24580966/error-the-command-android-failed-using-cordova

Comment: I have to add ant after also.

Comment: Above answer, plus setting JAVA_HOME per http://stackoverflow.com/a/663726/948073 , worked for me.

Comment: In fact, you don't need to export `ANDROID_TOOLS` neither `ANDROID_PLATFORM_TOOLS`. Just setting `ANDROID_HOME` and updating `PATH` worked for me.

Comment: Another issue could be if you are using sudo with cordova, then the exports won't work. If that's your case, try executing cordova/ionic without sudo for building.