# Cordova, getting Error while adding android platform on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: android, cordova, ant, ionic-framework

I installed cordova and can create a new project without any problems.

However I'm getting the following error when trying to add android platform:

```
sudo cordova platform add android
Running platform task...
Adding platform android
Creating android project...

/home/tushar/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.5.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error: An error occurred while listing Android targets
    at /home/tushar/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.5.0/bin/lib/check_reqs.js:87:29
    at _rejected (/home/tushar/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.5.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:808:24)
    at /home/tushar/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.5.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:834:30
    at Promise.when (/home/tushar/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.5.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:1079:31)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/home/tushar/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.5.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:752:41)
    at /home/tushar/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.5.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:574:44
    at flush (/home/tushar/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.5.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
Error: /home/tushar/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.5.0/bin/create: Command failed with exit code 8
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:131:23)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:743:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:810:5)
Unable to add platform android. Please see console for more info.
```

I have **tried almost all of the solutions from stackoverflow** but none of them solved. 
I have added the path to android sdk, ant etc on ./bashrc file as following:

```
export HOME="/home/tushar"
export ANDROID_HOME="$HOME/Development/adt-bundle/sdk/tools"
export ANDROID_PLATFORM_TOOLS="$HOME/Development/adt-bundle/sdk/platform-tools"
export PATH="$ANDROID_HOME:$ANDROID_PLATFORM_TOOLS:$PATH"

export ANT_HOME="$HOME/Development/ant"
export PATH="$PATH:$ANT_HOME/bin"
```

But I am still getting the problem.

Any Suggestions???

**UPDATE**

These might be helpful to debug:

```
$ node -v
v0.10.25

$ npm -v
1.3.10

$ cordova -v
3.5.0-0.2.4

$ android list targets
Available Android targets:
----------
id: 1 or "android-19"
     Name: Android 4.4.2
     Type: Platform
     API level: 19
     Revision: 3
     Skins: HVGA, WXGA800, WVGA800 (default), WQVGA432, WXGA800-7in, WXGA720, QVGA, WVGA854, WQVGA400, WSVGA
 Tag/ABIs : default/armeabi-v7a
```

Comment: This solution mentioned in the below linked solved the problem for me-
http://stackoverflow.com/a/23981071/1084806

Comment: @AkashNidhiPS: As I mentioned above, I have already exported the required paths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a problem with your paths:
ANDROID_HOME should point to sdk folder, not sdk/tools

Also add ANDROID_TOOLS pointing to sdk/tools

All in all you need: 
JAVA_HOME, 
ANT_HOME, 
ANDROID_HOME,
ANDROID_PLATFORM_TOOLS, 
ANDROID_TOOLS, 
and maybe ANDROID_SDK_ROOT pointing to sdk as well.

P.S. and without sudo, yes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't have to execute "cordova platform add android" as a superuser.

Answer (score 0):

i struggled with the same issue all day.. it turned out i did not add the full path while exporting path variables...

a "shell" hand in our group suggested to run "pwd" to get the "present working directory" and then give export the exact path...it worked

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. My PATH was correct. No problems with access rights.
Also noted that the adt-emulator was running into an error.

In the end, it was missing libraries to allow the adt (which partially is 32 bit) to run on a 64 bit ubuntu system.

```
sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32z1-dev
```

resolved this and everything works.

Hope this helps to resolve this issue for other folks.

Answer (score 0):

Had exactly the same problem in LMDE and as answered by Ranunculus, I added the below directly in my terminal and it worked!

```
export ANDROID_HOME="$HOME/android-sdk-linux"
export ANDROID_TOOLS="$ANDROID_HOME/tools/"
export ANDROID_PLATFORM_TOOLS="$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools/"
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle"
export ANT_HOME="/usr/share/ant"
export PATH="$JAVA_HOME:$ANT_HOME:$ANDROID_HOME:$ANDROID_TOOLS:$ANDROID_PLATFORM_TOOLS:$PATH"
```

N.B: Couldnt comment on Ranunculus's answer and so posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue (though running on Windows, but still worth checking on your side) and found out that it was due to a [bug in Ant](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=43971). My Classpath ended with a " too, and I had to fix this by removing the " in my class path variable.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem trying hard added multiple configuration which do conflicts and one more thing I found that I had opened multiple terminals when I was updating path on one terminal and trying to execute the Cordova command on another I was still getting the same error so i tried echo $PATH on the first terminal which shows updated path but the other terminal while echoing did not show the updated path so finally I opened new terminal and started again yes this time it works, This kind of problem generally occurs in windows but I am not sure if the same happen on Linux but in my case it was, I hope this may help others newbie now my both Cordova and ionic commands are working fine thanks to the SO community for their support and guidance