# Ionic - Starting Project - Error Fetching Plugin - ionic-plugins-keyboard

Tags: node.js, git, cordova, plugins, proxy

I have problem starting a project. `ionic start myApp2`

Here's the error that I got:

```
  Fetching plugin "org.apache.cordova.device" via plugin registry
  Fetching plugin "org.apache.cordova.console" via plugin registry
  Fetching plugin "https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-plugins-keyboard" via git clone
  Error: Command failed: fatal: Could not change back to 'C:/Windows/System/myApp2': No such file or directory
  at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:648:15)
  at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
  at maybeClose (child_process.js:756:16)
  at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:823:5)
  Unable to add plugins. Perhaps your version of Cordova is too old. Try up
  (npm install -g cordova), removing this project folder, and trying again.
```

I just installed Cordova and Ionic so I don't think their versions are an issue. Here's what I've done throughout installation.

1. `npm config set proxy http://...`
2. `npm config set https-proxy http://...`
3. `git config --global http.proxy http://...`
4. `git config --global https.proxy http://...`
5. `npm install -g cordova ionic`
6. Make changes in registry as guided here: http://www.jasonwatmore.com/post/2014/04/02/Ionic-Framework-Getting-ionic-start-appName-Working-Behind-a-Proxy.aspx
7. Created the plugman/git directory manually

I couldn't find this same error discussed other than the closest being the one below (which I believe is solved with step 7 above)

`Error: Command failed: fatal: could not create work tree dir C:\Users\DAVIDH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\plugman\git\...'.: No such file or directory`

And myApp2 does exist and in its plugin directory I can see both org.apache.cordova.device and org.apache.cordova.console. I tried reinstalling Node.js, Android SDK, Git, Cordova and Ionic just to be stuck with this error again.

Edit: I also have these in PATH:

```
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.5.0_08\bin;
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.5.0_08\bin;
  C:\Users\mohamada\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\tools;
  C:\Users\mohamada\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platforms;
  C:\Users\mohamada\Downloads\apache-ant-1.9.4\bin;
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin;
  C:\Program Files\nodejs\;
  C:\Users\mohamada\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\bin;
  C:\Users\mohamada\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\bin
```

Thanks in advance for the help,
Atikah

Comment: Your working directory when you run `ionic start myApp2` isn't `c:\Windows\System`, is it?

Comment: @kindasimple it's C:\Windows\System32.

Comment: You'll want to create your project elsewhere.

Comment: @kindasimple your suggestion helped me when I encountered error as discussed here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23960763/error-on-adding-platform-in-ionic-framework-on-windows). Thanks!