# Why does javac throw compile errors when my IDE does not?

Tags: java, shell, intellij-idea, command-line-interface, javac

I'm using IntelliJ for java development. I want to run my application on another host which I only have shell access to.

When I run my application locally, it's all fine and dandy. When I attempt to compile the code on the remote host, I get:

```
usr@host1:~/mp1/src$ javac -cp ../ Control.java
Control.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
    private static Node genNode = null;
                   ^
  symbol:   class Node
  location: class Control
Control.java:25: error: cannot find symbol
            genNode = new Node(hostname);
                          ^
  symbol:   class Node
  location: class Control
2 errors
```

The file `Node.java` is in the same directory:

```
mp1
├── src
│   ├── ClientControl.java
│   ├── Control.java
│   ├── Node.java
│   ├── Registrar.java
│   ├── ServerControl.java
│   ├── UX.java
├── lib
│   └── kryonet-2.21-all.jar
```

I can't compile locally either, unless it's from within the IDE, so I assume I'm just not doing something right. What am I missing? I just want to be able to run my application from a shell, I don't really care how.

Comment: probably you have a library in your project in your IDE, you don't have in your basic lib folder, so the compiler can't find it

Comment: Hm, maybe so? I added my lib tree to the post.. any idea how to fix it so the compiler can see it?

Comment: just check have you configured your `JAVA_HOME` to test just try command `echo %JAVA_HOME%`

Comment: Check which libraries you added in the ide, and add those to your lib of your basic Java folder

Comment: @SaviNuclear - hm, `echo $JAVA_HOME` displays nothing.

Comment: Please show a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem. We don't know what packages your code is in or anything like that. You could try just compiling all your code at once: `javac -cp .. *.java`

Comment: You need to add the libraries to the classpath. Use `javac -cp <path to jar> *.java`

Comment: You need to add any library you are using to the compiler classpath using the `-cp` parameter. Please see the javac manual: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html#userclasspath

Comment: @JonSkeet -- when I try to compile all at once, I just get `Error: Could not find or load main class ClientControl.java`

Comment: @MrDuk: That sounds like an error when you *run* it (due to not running it properly - you don't specify a `.java` file when trying to run the code, you just specify the class name).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to correctly set the classpath when you compile.

There is a problem in your classpath. Since you have set only the parent directory as your classpath. You have to include `src` too, since it contains your other source files.

Try:

```
javac  -cp .:../lib/kryonet-2.21-all.jar Control.java
```

Comment: Cool, this looks like it built the `.class` files properly. Now I've no clue how to execute my application. I've tried `java UX.java`, which contains my `main()`, but it just says `Could not find or load main class UX.java`

Comment: You execute the application with complied bytecode (.class), not source files. Again, correctly include all your complied classes and libraries in the classpath.

Comment: Try java  -cp .:../lib/kryonet-2.21-all.jar UX

Comment: Bingo! thanks a bunches. Bonus points - is my project laid out wonky? Should I have this organized differently, or is it common to have to specify this stuff at the cli?

Comment: Your structure is fine for a simple/learning project. In practice, "java/javac" are rarely used directly in Java world. You either use IDE or use build tools like Maven.

Answer (score 0):

Find /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.x.x-openjdk

```
vim /etc/profile
```

add these two lines:

```
export JAVA_HOME="path that you found"

export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

For more reference you can try:- [How to set JAVA_HOME in Linux for all users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24641536/how-to-set-java-home-in-linux-for-all-users)