# Why echo $JAVA_HOME is not same for all users

Tags: linux

I am using CentOS 6.5 version. I got sudo permissions and installed java, and set up `JAVA_HOME` this way .

```
$ cat /root/.bash_profile

# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
        . ~/.bashrc
fi

# User specific environment and startup programs
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64

PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin

export PATH
```

And now when i did

```
$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64
```

But once i logout and do

```
$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/local/jdk
```

Could you please tell me how do i set java_home for all users ??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set JAVA\_HOME in Linux for all users](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24641536/608639)

Answer (score 0):

```
vi /etc/profile
export JRE_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64
export PATH=$PATH:$JRE_HOME/bin

export JAVA_HOME=/your-path-to-java
export JAVA_PATH=$JAVA_HOME

export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

Comment: Thank you but its not working still the path is being shown as /usr/local/jdk

Comment: Yes because the above code sets your JRE path not Java Path. set export JAVA_HOME=/usr.local/jdk and then export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin. This will set your path accurately. OR change JRE_HOME to JAVA_PATH and all will be set

Comment: One more thing please also activate path settings by using this command. source /etc/profile OR ./etc/profile so path take effect immediately

Comment: I did exactly what you mentioned changed JRE_HOME to JAVA_PATH , but still the same issue exits

Comment: Sorry change JRE_HOME to JAVA_HOME and ran comman source /etc/profile

Comment: if i do so how jre_home will be set ?? if u don't mind can u please provide met the updated script ??

Comment: export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64
export JAVA_PATH=$JAVA_HOME

export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin then source /etc/profile

Comment: I need to run tomcat also that JRE_HOME also , so do i need to do the same for setting up JRE_HOME also ??

Comment: Look dear you have to set JRE_HOME and JAVA_HOME both as I said in my answer. Please follow it and set both. which version of tomcat you are using as you have to set its path as well.

Comment: I shall be more than happy to fix your this problem as well as Tomcat if any. I believe you also need mod_jk connector to serve tomcat pages without port. Let me know if you have any problem with mod_jk or Tomcat

Comment: I believe you also need mod_jk connector to serve tomcat pages without port. Let me know if you have any problem with mod_jk or Tomcat

Comment: Please write here the output of # echo $JAVA_HOME and # echo $PATH?

Comment: Please response to provided answers as this helps to the visitors to get understood which answer fixed your problem. Please mark the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

---

System settings for java, CentOS ,,, for all users :

```
# /usr/sbin/alternatives --config java
```

---