# Tomcat window prints an error and closes

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

I'm trying to start Tomcat, but the window prints an error and closes before I can read it. The logs don't update. Does anybody know how to keep it open?
Thanks.

Comment: did you try to run it from shell/command line? If it doesn't resolve, you can try to use some screen capture tool where you can examine all frames, maybe it helps.

Comment: Yes, I executed catalina.bat from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code as the last line in the batch file (.bat)

> pause

Answer (score 0):

It's common to happen when the required environment variable `JAVA_HOME` is not defined or is incorrect. You can add `pause` at the end of the .bat (before :end) or if I'm right try this to solve the original problem:

- If using Windows, follow [this](https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/setting-the-java_home-variable-in-windows-8895.html) instructions.
- Under Linux [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24641536/how-to-set-java-home-in-linux-for-all-users).
- Under Mac OS X [this](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-set-java_home-environment-variable-on-mac-os-x/).