# How to set Java home default across all users in Ubuntu

Tags: java, oracle, ubuntu

I am installing Oracle JDK 8 in the machine as a root user in Ubuntu, But already Open JDK is installed in the machine.

```
# Install Oracle JDK
add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
apt-get -y update
echo "oracle-java8-installer shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true" | sudo debconf-set-selections
apt-get install -y --force-yes oracle-java8-installer

# set JAVA_HOME
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
echo "export JAVA_HOME=${JAVA_HOME}" >> /etc/profile
echo "export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH" >> /etc/profile
source /etc/profile

echo "Oracle JDK installation completed"
echo "echo JAVA_HOME: $JAVA_HOME"
```

I want to use Oracle JDK 8 for all Java process.

At the end of script, I am print JAVA_HOME. It is printed as expected like below

```
echo JAVA_HOME: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
```

After installation is completed, I am logging into the machine as normal user. I see JAVA_HOME is set as openjdk as below:-

```
 echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
```

Even I logged in as root user and I see the same as above.

How can I set Oracle JDK 8 as JAVA_HOME across all users?

I am not sure, Will Java applications running in that machines using Oracle JDK or OpenJDK?

Comment: part of your installation writes to /etc/profile this makes it default for all users.

Comment: @Oleg Then why its showing OpenJdk JAVA_HOME when everytime logging into the machine as normal or root users?

Comment: Then you have JAVA_HOME in some other init file set to openjdk

Comment: @Oleg Yes. I have JAVA_HOME in /etc/environment. I have appended Oracle java home path to /etc/environment. But still it doesn't reflect oracle java home when I login every time.

Comment: There are other init files, there is probably some canonical answer about init files on askubuntu if not you should ask this question there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set JAVA\_HOME in Linux for all users](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24641536/608639)

Answer (score 0):

For ubuntu you can set the environment variable in

```
/etc/environment
```

Also you can have a look at [update-alternatives](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141791/is-there-a-way-to-update-all-java-related-alternatives) command

Comment: Even If I set Oracle java home in /etc/environment. It works when I do source /etc/environment
But when I do re-login in to the machine, java home defaults to open jdk.

Comment: update-java-alternatives -l
java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64       1081       /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64
java-8-oracle                  1081       /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
root@ubuntu:~# update-java-alternatives -s java-8-oracle
root@ubuntu:~# echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64.
Still I see Open JDK .

Comment: try with `sudo update-alternatives --config java` and `sudo update-alternatives --config javac`

Comment: also check the output of the `update-java-alternatives --list`

Comment: sudo update-alternatives --config java
There are 2 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

  Selection    Path                                            Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java          1081      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1081      manual mode
* 2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java          1081      manual mode

Comment: sudo update-alternatives --config javac
There are 2 choices for the alternative javac (providing /usr/bin/javac).

  Selection    Path                                         Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/javac          1081      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac   1081      manual mode
* 2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/javac          1081      manual mode

Comment: update-java-alternatives --list
java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64       1081       /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64
java-8-oracle                  1081       /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle

Comment: strange alternatives are set properly try `reboot`