# use default jdk of android sdk for other purpose

Tags: java, android, sdk, environment-variables

can we use open-jdk which comes with android studio and it's sdk by default to write other java programs in some different editor like vim? If yes then what are the environment variables need to set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to File > Project Structure > [Platform Settings] > SDKs to find your jdk path. Then follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24641536/how-to-set-java-home-in-linux-for-all-users) for Linux.

Comment: Specify your OS please.

Comment: My OS is linux.