# how to setup android development environment in ubuntu for react native

Tags: react-native

i am using nodejs --version
    v0.10.25 and npm --version 5.6.0 i also installed all the required things
    like node, npm ,also installed cli of react native ,android sdk, also add            Android sdk into PATH, using virtual device and set device ID to udev rules.
    And my file structure is :
    drwxrwxr-x   5 aspl aspl   4096 Feb 16 15:17 android
    -rw-rw-r--   1 aspl aspl   1184 Feb 16 15:17 App.js
    -rw-rw-r--   1 aspl aspl     43 Feb 16 15:17 app.json
    -rw-rw-r--   1 aspl aspl    119 Feb 16 15:17 index.android.js
    drwxrwxr-x 622 aspl aspl  20480 Feb 16 15:17 node_modules
    -rw-rw-r--   1 aspl aspl    448 Feb 16 15:17 package.json
    -rw-rw-r--   1 aspl aspl 266340 Feb 16 15:17 package-lock.json
    drwxrwxr-x   2 aspl aspl   4096 Feb 16 15:17 **tests**
    still i got the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.security.ProviderException: java.security.InvalidKeyException: EC parameters error


Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is due to not setting up JAVA_HOME. Set it with steps from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24641536/how-to-set-java-home-in-linux-for-all-users/24641640#24641640) .

```
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk"
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

save above code to your save that to your .bashrc file and run again

Comment: try  cleaning the project "cd android && ./gradlew clean && cd .."  and confirm if jdk is in path by "echo $JAVA_HOME"

Comment: ./gradlew: line 164: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_161/bin/java: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
./gradlew: line 164: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_161/bin/java: Success

Comment: It maybe that you have installed 32-bit JDK environment in 64-bit Linux system. Try and fix the JDK environment according to you system.