# The program 'jshell' is currently not installed when trying to run jshell on Ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu-16.04, jshell

I have downloaded and "manually" installed JDK 10 for Linux 64bit edition (for Ubuntu 16.04),
[Oracle Java SE Development Kit](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk10-downloads-4416644.html)
(note: I wanted to download the Java9 JDK but this is no longer supported and I was referred to the Java 10 SE Development kit instead).

When I try running `jshell` from a terminal window I get the following error,

> The program 'jshell' is currently not installed. To run 'jshell'
>   please ask your administrator to install the package
>   'openjdk-9-jdk-headless' You will have to enable the component called
>   'universe'

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I dont know why the message is asking me to install openjdk when I have installed the classic java version. When I run "which jshell" I dont get any details returned.

Can anyone help me get `jshell` installed and working ?

Comment: According to your second screenshot, it seems that JShell is correctly installed. Did you try to run JShell in that folder using `./jshell`? If it works, the problem is just path configuration.

Comment: thanks Mincong - I just tried that and yes that works ! I am a bit confused, if I use "update-alternatives" to configure my java version - does that only expose the files that I have configured i.e. "java" and "javac" ? do I need to add the java 'bin' directory to my path explicitly as well inorder to access all the other files in the `bin` directory ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know about update-alternatives and I don't use Linux... I'll let other to help you on this field. The only thing for sure is that the `bin` folder of JDK must be present in your PATH—so that you can call `jshell` directly.

Comment: I don't see the Java Directory in your PATH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JShell` is a development tool. You should download and install the **Java Development Kit** to run `jshell`, not just the Java Runtime Environment.

Comment: I do have that - if you check the link I posted above you can see what I downloaded. I just checked the "bin" directory and can see that "jshell" is included there.

Comment: @robbie70 how about including /bin in PATH then?

Comment: @robbie70 Then your `PATH` variable includes the JRE installation's `bin` directory. You will have to change its value to point to the JDK's bin directory, instead.

Comment: Eugene / Ernest - I dont have java included in my `path`. Instead I used `update-alternatives` to configure my java version.

Comment: Then that's where the change must be done. Check this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/315646/update-java-alternatives-vs-update-alternatives-config-java

Answer (score 1):

On Linux, and specificallly Ubuntu, development tools are not best installed via `apt`.  The exception to prove the rule is `RVM`, which is installed via `apt` purely so that it will download ruby and ruby gems dynamically outside of apt.

For Java, the equivalent is `SDKman`, which is installed via `curl`.  Once you have `SDKman` *then* you can install `Java` and other `Java` type tools.

`SDKman` in action:

```
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ sdk list java
================================================================================
Available Java Versions
================================================================================
     12.ea.20-open                                                              
     11.0.1-zulu                                                                
 > * 11.0.1-open                                                                
     10.0.2-zulu                                                                
     10.0.2-open                                                                
     9.0.7-zulu                                                                 
     9.0.4-open                                                                 
   * 8.0.192-zulu                                                               
     8.0.191-oracle                                                             
     7.0.201-zulu                                                               
     6.0.119-zulu                                                               
     1.0.0-rc-10-grl                                                            
     1.0.0-rc-9-grl                                                             
     1.0.0-rc-8-grl                                                             


================================================================================
+ - local version
* - installed
> - currently in use
================================================================================
thufir@dur:~$
```

Generally, `umake`, or `Ubuntu Make`, will install `IDE` or other development tools.  Currently, `umake` is best installed as a `snap`.

The upshot is to first install `SDKman`, then `snap`, then use `snap` to install `umake`.  Between `umake` and `SDKman` your tools should be up to date.

(Ruby uses a similar `RVM`, which inspired `SDKman`.)

Answer (score 0):

I followed the tip given by Ernest Kiwele and others above and set-up my JAVA_HOME partly as described in 
[How to set JAVA_HOME in Linux for all users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24641536/how-to-set-java-home-in-linux-for-all-users?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)
but also by creating a `sh` script in my profile.d directory. Thank you for the help.

[image]

I dont feel completely comfortable with my solution since I have configured my Java using `update-alternatives`. I dont know why people advise to use `update-alternatives` to set the version of Java to use if the other depending variables aren't set-up at the same time.

[image]