# Java version issue in linux server

Tags: java, linux, jdk1.7

How to change java version to jdk1.7.0_80?

**java -version**
java version "1.6.0_41"
$JAVA_HOME

**$JAVA_HOME**: -bash: /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_80: is a directory

I have to update jdk version to 1.7.0_80 and i installed as well,but when i enter java -version,i am getting old version only

Comment: You need sudo access to modify such settings. Else, you should use the canonical java path to run the above command. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24641640/5051731)

Comment: What is the type of Linux server (redhat, debian, version?)? What is the source of this jdk (oracle, openjdk, rpm, deb?)?

Comment: I would consider migrating to Java 8 if not Java 11 asap. Java 8 is End of Public updates soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1)Use following command to detect installed java version

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

[image]

(2)Select selection number & Enter

(3)Re-Check java version with

```
java -version
```

Answer (score 1):

First remove (puge) all installed JDK or JRE on your system

```
  sudo apt-get purge openjdk-\*    //(for exemple to remove open jdk on ubuntu)
```

For other steps you can follow steps in this [link](https://www.wikihow.com/Install-Oracle-Java-on-Ubuntu-Linux)

Answer (score 0):

In CentOs:
1. vim /etc/profile , then edit '$JAVA_HOME'.
2. source /etc/profile, make the configuration take effect.
3. java -version, validate version.

Linux-like systems are similar. 
(If it does'n worked. Reboot.)