# Jmeter java not found

Tags: java, java-8, jmeter

Unable to launch JMeter from terminal getting this error:

> ./jmeter.sh: 98: [: Illegal number:  ./jmeter: 128: [: Illegal number:
>   ./jmeter: 192: ./jmeter: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk
>   amd64/jre/bin/java/bin/java: not found

I have Java 8 on my system and I have `java home` set on my system too, but JMeter is not able to get it.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24641536/how-to-set-java-home-in-linux-for-all-users

Comment: @user7294900 - i have the java home set correctly , but still m unable to launch jmeter

Comment: what version of jmeter is it ? what is the OS ? type uname -a

Comment: @UBIKLOADPACK - apache-jmeter-5.0 , ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set JAVA\_HOME in Linux for all users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24641536/how-to-set-java-home-in-linux-for-all-users)

Comment: @user7294900  thnks  ,i was doing a very silly mistake , i had the java verion 1.8 and in java home i have set the path as /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64 , just updated it to /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64 and it worked

Answer (score 3):

Try these

1.Open terminal and run

```
readlink -f $(which java)

OUTPUT:

/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java
```

2.run:  `echo $JAVA_HOME`

```
OUTPUT:
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
```

3.if you see the path your config is fine if not

use [this to setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24641536/how-to-set-java-home-in-linux-for-all-users) `JAVA_HOME`

Don't forget to run `source /etc/profile`

**Note:** In the question, you have added

> I have java home set on my system to

it has to be `JAVA_HOME` nothing else

Comment: It worked i just did one silly mistake i had java version 1.8, and in java home path i mentioned  /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64, just updated it to  /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64