# React native JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, react-native, redux

I am new to the `react native.` I am using a `linux machine`. I am trying to run an application.

Now, Here what I have done ,

I already have java installed in my machine .So, that time I have added,

in my `profile`

I have following env variables .

```
export JAVA_HOME='/usr/local/java'
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/jdk1.8.0_121/bin
```

Now, after that I have installed the `android studio` in my one of folders,

which is `/home/softwares/android-studio`.

That time I have added the env variables in the profile file.which are

```
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Android/Sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

Now, my project folder is like ,

```
/home/projectWork/native/app
```

Added the script in the package.json file , but there

it is giving me this error .

```
JS server not recognized, continuing with build...
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && ./gradlew installDebug)...

ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: /usr/local/java

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.
```

Now, I am not getting a way to resolve this issue . Can any one help me with this ?

Comment: The JAVA_HOME variable is pointing to the wrong directory it should be `/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_121`

Comment: what about the  JS server not recognized, continuing with build... is that okay ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set your `JAVA_HOME` to the actual JDK:

```
export JAVA_HOME='/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_121'
```

Answer (score 0):

For windows user that is downgrading from JDK 17 to JDK 8, you need to ensure a few things:

1. Set the java home and path correctly.
2. Remove JDK 17 folder from program files path.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set the JAVA_HOME in your Environemnt.
For Linux users. check these solutions:
[How to set JAVA_HOME in Linux for all users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24641536/how-to-set-java-home-in-linux-for-all-users)

Answer (score 0):

**Set the java home in MacOs Monterey**
1 Set up JAVA_HOME in environment variable
1.1 Open your shell profile file for editing using a text editor like nano or vim. You can use the nano editor as an example:
**nano ~/.zshrc**   # For Zsh. // Run that command in your Zsh terminal

2 Add the following line to set the JAVA_HOME variable to the correct Java installation path. Make sure to replace the path with the one you mentioned in your output:
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/Your JDK Version/Contents/Home.

3 Save the file and exit the text editor. In nano, you can do this by pressing Ctrl + O to write changes, then Enter to confirm the file name, and finally Ctrl + X to exit.
4 Source the profile file to apply the changes to your current terminal session. >>> **source ~/.zshrc**   # For Zsh   //Run that command in your  terminal
5 Verify that the JAVA_HOME variable has been set correctly by running
**echo $JAVA_HOME**.  //Run that command in your  terminal

6 Finally, try running your React Native project again:
**npx react-native run-android**

**

> This should resolve the "JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory"
> error, and React Native should be able to use the correct Java
> installation for building your Android project.

**