# how to fix IntelliJ IDEA installing error?

Tags: ubuntu, command-line

I am trying to install IntelliJ IDEA in my ubuntu system, but while installing I am getting an error like this `- bash: ./idea.sh: Permission denied`.

I used this command line for install `./idea.sh`.

I've tried some other commands, too. but nothing works.

anyone, please tell me how to fix this

Answer (score 1):

You need to add sudo before the command.

```
sudo ./idea.sh
```

If any write access error occured try following commands.

```
chmod +x idea.sh
sudo ./idea.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

run your command with `sudo`, like:

```
sudo ./idea.sh
```

or add needed permission by `chmod`, then you can simply run it by `./idea.sh`

Comment: Thanks Majid. it's working but again one more error 'no jdk found. please validate either pycharm jdk jdk_home or java_home ' like this

Comment: for each one you need to set the default language packages and files. check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24641536/how-to-set-java-home-in-linux-for-all-users