# Learn JavaFX without IDE

Tags: java, terminal, javafx-8, vimeo, parrot-os

i want to learn `javaFX` but online sources only show installation and setup in an IDE like: `Netbeans` , `Eclipse` , `IntelliJ` etc.

but i want to do it without IDE 
ie : using only Terminal and a text editor(vim).

what is the steps to set up `JavaFX` for a projects and run it without any IDE.

JDK version:- 11.0.4 
Os :-  Parrot OS

Comment: Why do you want to do it without IDE ie using only Terminal and a text editor(vim)? It will be difficult for you to compile, execute, debug etc. without an IDE.

Comment: Install Java. Download the JavaFX SDK and install that as well (via Gluon or possibly via a package manager). If you don't want to download the SDK then use Maven or Gradle and pull in JavaFX from Maven Central. Use Java from the command line as normal (using a build tool such as Maven or Gradle will significantly simplify things). Configure Vim in whatever way that's accomplished (never used it).

Comment: @Slaw I suggest you make an Answer of your Comment, so that it can be accepted.

Comment: @Slaw thank you for the answer . i like to write everything on my own just for educational purpose . and about your answer i am already familiar with the steps you mentioned . but i am confused about the location and package and etc where i should install javaFX as importing would cause error if not done correctly i guess.

Comment: If you download the JavaFX SDK you'd "install" it where you install all your other programs. Then you add it to the `--module-path` when you're compiling and executing your application. If you use Maven or Gradle and download it from Maven Central then the JavaFX dependencies will be cached in each tool's respective local repository. Then the build tools, when configured correctly, will handle setting the command line arguments for you. Note that JavaFX is just like any other (platform-specific) third-party dependency now.

Comment: You can just follow a maven tutorialand run it using `mvn javafx:run` or `mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=fully.qualified.MainClass`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. first download your desired version of java i would recommend openjdk-11 
   `sudo apt install openjdk-11-jdk`
2. download the javaFx from [here](https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/)
3. set the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable to the JDK installation directory ([this answer would help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24641536/how-to-set-java-home-in-linux-for-all-users))
4. set the `PATH_TO_FX` environment variable by the same way as above but the path should point to /lib
   eg: export PATH_TO_FX=path/to/javafx-sdk-11/lib
5. compile and run your javafx code like this :

`javac --module-path $PATH_TO_FX --add-modules javafx.controls [filename].java`

`java --module-path $PATH_TO_FX --add-modules javafx.controls [filename]`