# Change the default Java path to other path in FreeBSD

Tags: java, freebsd, java-home, path-variables

I have script to get the java path from this command: `readlink -f $(which java)`.

But it displays wrong path : **/usr/local/bin/javavm**

While I need to have this path :  **/usr/local/openjdk8/bin/java**

I tried to give export command:  **export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/openjdk8/**,   but the issue remains same.

I tried this post as well : https://stackoverflow.com/a/39691105/10220825

and this post  : https://askubuntu.com/a/554052/905016

I also tried : **sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/javavm /usr/local/openjdk8/bin/java**
but it results, `ln: /usr/local/openjdk8/bin/java: File exists` and issue remain same.

I dont want to hardcode it, neither I want to use other command like `which java` or `echo $JAVA_HOME` as the script is getting the expected result in Linux but only problems with FreeBSD machine.

I also dont want to apply any parsing like `awk` or `sed`  from the output of `readlink -f $(which java)`.

Can someone suggest me how to change the value from `readlink -f $(which java)`.

Comment: `readlink` does *not* report the wrong path. Do you want to change the default path to something else? Try [`update-alternative`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/update-alternatives).

Comment: You might want to replace the `unix` tag by the actual Linux flavor you use (e.g `bsd`).

Comment: What are you actually trying to do here? Why are these paths significant?

Comment: (and the correct `ln` syntax is `ln -s <source> [destination] `)

Comment: @Matthieu, I have tried with the same`ln` syntax, the result is same

Comment: Then `rm <destination> && ln -s <source> <destination>` should do it. But again, it depends on your Linux flavor. `update-alternatives` is usually the preferred way.

Comment: @Matthieu, I am working on the FreeBSD machine and `update-alternatives is only Linux command..`

Comment: Why do you think this is wrong? What isn’t working? What you’re seeing is the expected behaviour on FreeBSD, and everything should work fine.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, I am not able to change the java path from `javam` to `openjdk/binjava` path to read it from `readlink -f $(which java)`

Comment: @Ratnesh That doesn’t answer my question. **Why** do you want to do that?

Comment: @KonradRudolph, Actually, I need to profile one Java application through one profiler but it seems profiler does not able to report application's related data with the javavm  while doing the same thing with /usr/local/openjdk8/bin/java it reports the application's related data..

Comment: Note: FreeBSD is not Linux. Removed tag.

Answer (score 6):

What you’re seeing is the [documented behaviour on FreeBSD](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=javavm&manpath=FreeBSD+12.1-RELEASE+and+Ports).

If you want to select a specific Java version, set the `JAVA_VERSION` environment variable, e.g.:

```sh
JAVA_VERSION=8+ javac MyClass.java
```

If you want to find out what version is being run, set `JAVAVM_DRYRUN=yes`:

```sh
JAVAVM_DRYRUN=yes java

JAVAVM_DRYRUN=yes JAVA_VERSION=11 java
```