# Netbeans profiler not working with JDK 17

Tags: java, openjdk-17, netbeans-13

When I try to run the profiler on my web app, netbeans tells me I need to run a calibration first. So I go to Tools > Options > Java > Profiler > General > Manage Calibration Data and do the calibration.

Starting profiling afterwards I see following in the console:

```
ant -f /home/codyline/myApp -Dnb.internal.action.name=profile -Ddirectory.deployment.supported=true 
-DforceRedeploy=false -Dnb.wait.for.caches=true "-Drun.jvmargs.ide= -agentpath:/home/codyline/netbeans/
netbeans-13/netbeans/profiler/lib/deployed/jdk16/linux-amd64/libprofilerinterface.so= 
/home/codyline/netbeans/netbeans-13/netbeans/profiler/lib, 5140,10 -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError 
-XX:HeapDumpPath=/home/codyline/myApp/nbproject/private/profiler" 
-Dbrowser.context=/home/codyline/myApp profile

profile:
init:
deps-module-jar:
deps-ear-jar:
deps-jar:
library-inclusion-in-archive:
library-inclusion-in-manifest:
compile:
compile-jsps:
Starting Payara Server 5.2022.1
Payara Server 5.2022.1 is running.
```

And nothing happens!
So Netbeans is trying to use JDK 16 which is not installed on my machine.
I need to do the profiling with JDK 17.
NOTE: same problem with Netbeans 12.6.

How can I fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seams you are using Linux on amd64 architecture. This can occur when your JAVA_HOME environment variable is pointing wrong directory.

```
echo $JAVA_HOME # this command shows your java version
```

If it is not JDK 17, use this link to change the variable [How to set JAVA_HOME in Linux for all users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24641536/how-to-set-java-home-in-linux-for-all-users)

Comment: That can not be the reason, cause I set ```netbeans_jdkhome="/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64"``` in netbeans.conf