# ERROR: Cannot determine JDK version, please set $JAVA_HOME.\n $JAVAC_VERSION is "javac 11.0.16"

Tags: java, bazel, arm64

I am using Linux aarch64 machine. I use miniconda3 and create a virtual environment in miniconda3. I want to install tensorflow using bazel. Therefore I first download the bazel zip file.

When I run the compile.sh file after extracting the zip file of "bazel", I got the following error

```
INFO: You can skip this first step by providing a path to the bazel binary as second argument:
INFO:    ./compile.sh compile /path/to/bazel
  Building Bazel from scratch
ERROR: Cannot determine JDK version, please set $JAVA_HOME.\n $JAVAC_VERSION is "javac 11.0.16"
```

When I search Java version ,
`java --version`
I got this

```
openjdk version "11.0.16" 2022-07-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.16+8-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu120.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.16+8-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu120.04, mixed mode)
```

May  I know how can I solve the issue?
When I check `echo $JAVA_HOME"`, I got nothing. Do I also need to set JAVAC_VERSION? If yes, may  I know how can I set both Java_home and javac_version?
Thank you.

Comment: No help from me, just info. JAVA_HOME was a (cross-platform) requirement of the JDK, that now no longer holds. It seems bazel still uses it. Alternative java versions side-by-side: https://askubuntu.com/questions/315646/update-java-alternatives-vs-update-alternatives-config-java

Comment: @user16320675 yes and then there was also JDK_HOME.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you didn't set JAVA_HOME environment variable

Please check [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/drive/drive_os_5.1.6.1L/nvvib_docs/index.html#page/DRIVE_OS_Linux_SDK_Development_Guide/Architecture/config_env_variables_setup.html) to manually setup environment variables.

Here you should set `export JAVA_HOME=<java_path>`

Comment: May I know how to check which java_path my linux is using?

Comment: When I search java path in google, it shows ```export PATH=/usr/java/<JDK Directory> bin:$PATH" But when I check /usr/ folder, there is no java folder. it has only ``` src, share, sbin, local , libexec, lib, include, games, bin folder```

Comment: May this link work for you?
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21689/how-to-find-path-where-jdk-installed

Comment: Hello Phillip, when I check ```which java```, it gives ```/usr/bin/java```. When I check ```whereis java```, it gives ```java: /usr/bin/java /usr/share/java /usr/share/man/man1/java.1.gz```. May I know which java directory should I set for export JAVA_HOME?

Comment: Please run this command : `ls -l /etc/alternatives/java`
And let me know the result.

Comment: You should `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-arm64/bin/java`
Did you try without quotes?

Comment: ```lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 43 Aug 18 11:47 /etc/alternatives/java -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-arm64/bin/java```
When I ```export JAVA_HOME='/usr/bin/java'```, and compile the bazel's ./compile.sh, It gives ERROR: JAVA_HOME (/usr/bin/java) is not a path to a working JDK.
I also tried with ```export JAVA_HOME='/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-arm64/bin/java'```, and compile, it also give java_home is not a path to a working JDK

Comment: Without quotes ```export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-arm64/bin/java``` also give the same error ```ERROR: JAVA_HOME (/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-arm64/bin/java) is not a path to a working JDK.
```

Comment: `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-arm64` should work.
And please restart your OS.
Otherwise, try this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24641536/how-to-set-java-home-in-linux-for-all-users

Comment: I tried both ```/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-arm64``` and ```/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-arm64/bin/java```. I also restarted the OS. I got the same issue. I want to know when ```export JAVA_HOME=<PATH TO JAVA>``` is added, in the .bashrc file, how does it modify? Because when I check the .bashrc file, it does not modify anything/

Comment: Did you try adding to .bashrc manually?

Comment: No, I did not add manually to .bashrc. I check it but don't find export Java_Home line in the .bashrc.

Comment: Then please add it manually, restart your OS, and try again.

Comment: Should I add ```export JAVA_HOME='/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-arm64/bin/java'``` to the .bashrc file?

Comment: Without quotes. If it doesn't work, try with `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-arm64`. And please don't forget to restart your OS.

Comment: Hello Phillip, with and without quotes, give the same issue after restarting OS.
In the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24641536/how-to-set-java-home-in-linux-for-all-users, ```export JAVA_HOME="path that you found"

export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH```. inside that "path that you found", should I give ```/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-arm64``` or ```/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-arm64/bin/java```?

Comment: Please try both of them. But I recommend the latter form.

Comment: I got the same error after adding ```export JAVA_HOME="path that you found"

export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH``` to vim /etc/profile.

Comment: ```ERROR: JAVA_HOME (/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-arm64/bin/java) is not a path to a working JDK.``` May I know is it related to the JAVA_HOME path is not the path for working JDK ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set up an Environment Variable. Google "how to install JDK 8." You can get better answers there

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Philip for your input and advice.

The issue is solved by:

1. `ls -l /etc/alternatives/java` gives `etc/alternatives/java -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-arm64/`
2. `vim /etc/profile`
3. Press `I`
4. Add

   ```
   export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-arm64/bin/java

   export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
   ```
5. Reboot the os. `source /etc/profile`