# Failed to start LSB: Controls Apache Solr as a Service

Tags: java, service, solr

When I install any solr I am getting this:

```
solr.service - LSB: Controls Apache Solr as a Service
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/solr; generated)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2022-09-16 17:35:43 IST; 33min ago
       Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
    Process: 23476 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/solr start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Sep 16 17:35:43 himanshu-Inspiron-15-3567 su[23478]: (to solr) root on none
Sep 16 17:35:43 himanshu-Inspiron-15-3567 su[23478]: pam_unix(su-l:session): session opened for user solr by (uid=0)
Sep 16 17:35:43 himanshu-Inspiron-15-3567 solr[23492]: The currently defined JAVA_HOME (/usr/lib/jvm/openjdk-11) refers
Sep 16 17:35:43 himanshu-Inspiron-15-3567 solr[23492]: to a location where Java could not be found.  Aborting.
Sep 16 17:35:43 himanshu-Inspiron-15-3567 solr[23492]: Either fix the JAVA_HOME variable or remove it from the
Sep 16 17:35:43 himanshu-Inspiron-15-3567 solr[23492]: environment so that the system PATH will be searched.
Sep 16 17:35:43 himanshu-Inspiron-15-3567 su[23478]: pam_unix(su-l:session): session closed for user solr
Sep 16 17:35:43 himanshu-Inspiron-15-3567 systemd[1]: solr.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Sep 16 17:35:43 himanshu-Inspiron-15-3567 systemd[1]: solr.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 16 17:35:43 himanshu-Inspiron-15-3567 systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Controls Apache Solr as a Service.
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your problem is related to a JAVA_HOME that points to nonexistent location. Specify JAVA_HOME in your system settings and see if the problem persists [like this stackoverflow solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24641536/how-to-set-java-home-in-linux-for-all-users)