# Android Studio doesn't start on WSL (No JRE found)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, wsl-2

Step 1. Installed java on my WSL by running

```
sudo apt install default-jdk
```

when I run **java --version** it gives me **openjdk 11.0.18 2023-01-17**

Step 2. Installed **VcXsrv X Server** on my Windows 10. Configured it so I'm sure that it works (I mananged to start Ubuntu's calculator on it by running "**xcalc**" in the terminal)

Step 3. Downloaded Android Studio linux package and unzipped it in my home directory subfolder.

Now I am trying to start it by running "**sh studio.sh**" but an error from VcXsrv X Server is popping out:

> Cannot start Android Studio: No JRE found. Please make sure
> $STUDIO_JDK, $JDK_HOME, or $JAVA_HOME point to valid JRE installation.

What am I supposed to do? Does it need me to install JDK on Windows as well and set env variables there?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this error and this question while searching for a solution.

You can fix this by instead setting the `$STUDIO_JDK` variable to the `$JAVA_HOME` path. Hope this helps you also.

Comment: This is the right answer here. This is the answer that works and should be marked as best. Changing from $JAVA_HOME to $STUDIO_JDK and adding it to the $PATH worked for me without need of downgrading my java version. But the issue is that it only worked on Android Studio Electric El and below. I tried it with other newer versions like Giraffe and Hedgehog, but I still got issues.

Answer (score 0):

Running java binary does not tell you about JAVA_HOME variable. Run echo $JAVA_HOME to see if its present, if not check here how to set it: [How to set JAVA_HOME in Linux for all users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24641536/how-to-set-java-home-in-linux-for-all-users)

Comment: I did this, but this changed nothing.
Now it replies when I type echo $JAVA_HOME, with the right path, but the same error pops out when I'm trying to launch Android Studio

Comment: Maybe I have to install Java on Windows? (Because VcXsrv X Server worls there)

Answer (score 0):

I was in the same position for weeks, but I managed to get round it by downgrading Studio to [version 2021.1.1](https://developer.android.com/studio/archive)

And downgrading java to version 11 by running `sudo apt install openjdk-11-jre`. [Check this out](https://www.linuxcapable.com/how-to-install-openjdk-11-on-ubuntu-linux/) for further info on how and when to do this.

My next steps is to find out which is the latest version of each that I can use without breaking what now works.

Comment: Please what latest version of Android Studio did you download and it did not break? I have about 5 android studio zip files but none of them is working. But I haven't tried this jdk solution though.

Comment: Android Studio 2021.3.1 Dolphin just worked for me right now with java version 11.0.20. I need to use an android studio that supports AGP version 7.3.1.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but this helps me: [Can I run android studio on windows 10 Subsystem Linux](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1189343/can-i-run-android-studio-on-windows-10-subsystem-linux).

Main point:

1. In addition to VcXsrv you need to install xfce4 on the unix side
2. Install missing libraries with: `sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0 lib32stdc++6`
3. I also added `export DISPLAY=:0` in `/etc/profile` instead of `export DISPLAY=[unix ip]:0` like it says in the article

After all this I managed to run android studio on WSL